# How get numbers only out of a list collection that is mixed with text in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list collection that contains the following code:

```
List<string> results = list.Where(f => og.IsMatch(f)).ToList();
```

The code above returns all fields that contains numbers. However I now only want the list collection to bring back a collection with the numbers only and removing the text.

Comment: So what is the possible values of the individual string fields?

Comment: You want strings that are numbers (e.g. "100") or you want number part of a string (e.g. string = "aaa100", return "100")?

Comment: If I understood your question right and you want the result to contain `int`s instead of `string`s you could use `.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s))`

Comment: What does `og.ToString()` print? If you have an item with `12.345text56`, do you need to get back `12.34`, `56` as separate items? Or just `1234556`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want.

With this regex, you can remove all non numeric characters from a string. So you will be left numeric part only.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]*"); 
List<string> results = list.Where(f => og.IsMatch(f)).Select(x => regex.Replace(x, String.Empty)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this line of code. You are a genius! God bless your soul. One love :)